# Extend video monitors

Tags: video

How can I extend video to have 2 different programs running on different screens on my dell inspiron 3847 with HD Graphics 4600? I have 2 monitors with VGA only inputs and
PC has only 1 VGA, 1 HDMI and available USB. I bought a VGA to VGA splitter that I hooked up to the back of PC VGA port but it hangs PC when I try to boot. Do I need another video card?

Answer (score 0):

VGA splitters are a bit janky. Since you have HDMI - getting a HDMI to VGA adaptor would do the trick. You shouldn't need a second video card in *this* situation. The adaptors are active (and draw power from HDMI) but its still significantly cheaper and simpler than adding a video card.